# How to tell which file Apache is waiting for when WCHAN = flock_lock_file_wait

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flock

We're having an issue with our webservers in which more and more Apache processes are getting stuck waiting for file lock (caused by PHP flock()) to somehow resolve, but never does.  Eventually the site gets slower and slower, and finally stops completely, until Apache is restarted.

I'm working on the theory that somehow bad code is behind this, perhaps in our homegrown disk cache mechanism.  But I can't track it down. (We are running on Ubuntu.)

My question is, how can I tell what file or files it's getting stuck on?  If I could see where the hangup is, I could much more easily figure out where the bad code is. When I do this command:

```
ps -o pid,tt,user,fname,wchan -C apache2
```

I get this:

```
  730 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait  
 3085 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait  
 5393 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait  
 5397 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait  
11181 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait  
30280 ?        www-data apache2  flock_lock_file_wait
```

Is there any way for me to go from this to seeing which exact file Apache is locked on / waiting for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the **lsof** utiliy:

```
apt-get install lsof
```

lsof mean list open files. A lot of things can be done with it, `lsof -ni` will list opened network connections for example. For your apache processes you'll have to use the -p option (PID):

```
lsof -p 730
```

And you'll get all the opened files and libraries (eveything is a file on linux), so obviously you'll get your lock file.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this. Good thing for me, the lsof utility was already installed.  Unfortunately, the list of stuff I get is quite long for one of these processes -- including about a half-dozen different log files, one of which (I'm fairly certain) is my locked file.  I don't suppose there is some way to tell by looking at the lsof output which of these files might be in a 'stuck' or 'locked' position?

Comment: http://www.netadmintools.com/html/lsof.man.html go to OUTPUT then look at FD for NnRrWwUuXx meanings, different types of locks

Comment: if you think the answer is useful, vote for it, and as you're the asker check the green markup to accept it.

Comment: regilero - thank you very much (again), I tried to vote you up, but it tells me I don't have enough reputation points to do that.  However, I do think that you have very thoroughly answered this question, so I'll mark this as answered!  Thank you again.